# Unexcepted behaviour of columns

Tags: html, css

At the beginning sorry for my English skills.
I will try to explain my problem the best I can, so I've got 3 columns layout based on divs

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-left">
            <h1>O fdfas <span>fdas</span></h1><hr/>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="text">
                Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutru auctor. 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-center">
            <h1>fdas</h1><hr/>              
            <div class="box">
                <div class="text">
                Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac fac
                </div>                  

                <div class="text">
                Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Duis mollis, e
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
            <h1>Szybki <span>kontakt</span></h1><hr/>
            <div id="contact_box">
                <div class="address">lalala</div>
                <div class="contact">lalala</div>
                <div class="address">lalal</div>
                <div class="contact">lalala</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-left">test</div>
        <div class="col-center">test</div>
        <div class="col-right">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS file

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
}

.container .col-left {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 41px;
    width: 293px;
    outline: 1px solid green;
}

.container .col-center {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 41px;
    width: 293px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.container .col-right {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 292px;
    outline: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/1on11esn/
What can you see there? Two rows of columns but rendered not as I excepted.
They are overlapped and I excepted 2nd row should be underneath whole 1st row, whole 1st row I mean under that element which has the biggest height.
Sorry once more for my English skills. I tried almost everything and don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems.

Usually, you don't need to use both `float`s and `inline-block` rules on the same element. So I removed `float` rules from all of them. It seemed easier, because if I kept floats instead, I'd have to add a clearing (`clear: both`) div at the bottom of each container.

Next, the container `height` shouldn't be fixed (you can use `min-height` instead) but you should let it expand as its child element reqiure.

Next, you need to be careful with the width of every child inside a container, making sure it doesn't excel the size of the container.

See the fixed example here: http://jsfiddle.net/1on11esn/1/

All I did:

- removed float rules
- removed containers' height (they default to `auto`)
- reduced the right margins of child divs a bit (adjust them if needed)

And if you want to align them to the top, a simple `.container > div {vertical-align: top;}` should work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/1on11esn/3/

To overcome the inline-block white space issue, set `font-size: 0;` to the container elements and `font-size: initial;` to their children: http://jsfiddle.net/1on11esn/5/

That way you can keep your original widths without making additional modifications.

Comment: every column should be aligned to the top and margins and width of columns have to be like in my example, 
`2x293+292+2x41=960`

Comment: Yup, was just writing about that.

Comment: I'm still learning new things, thanks for explain me how to solve my problem. Now everything is clear

Comment: You're welcome! Both solutions are good, one is not better than the other, but rather it all depends on for what they're used for. The reason I chose inline-block approach is because you have a persistent and solid structure (three fixed columns).

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need here is a clearfix.

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1on11esn/2/) of your example using the clearfix technique.

Is basically adding these CSS rules to your container:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

You will need to use the clear when:

1. floated items can be taller than non-floated content inside the same container. The parent container doesn't stretch to match floated items.
2. if all children are floating.

Using the clearfix in the parent (container), the children will be self-cleared. The container will then automatically stretch to the necessary height.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to use it. This is a pretty standard workaround for this problem. You can have the clearfix rules declared in your CSS and simply put the clearfix class in any HTML element you might need.

Comment: @Shomz, I read your answer however, when I tried to make right margins like before, whole layout was bad

Comment: @alwaysLearning Yes, that happens with inline-block elements: `<div></div> <div></div>` will have a gap in between, while `<div></div><div></div>` won't. I've shown you how to deal with it and keep the original pixel sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 960px;
 margin:0 auto;
 outline: 1px solid red;
 height: 100px;
}

.container .col-left {

 margin-right: 41px;
 width: 293px;
 outline: 1px solid green;
}

.container .col-center {
 
 margin-right: 41px;
 width: 293px;
 outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.container .col-right {
 
 width: 292px;
 outline: 1px solid yellow;
}
.container div{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```